# ¿Cómo puedo agregar una nota al final de una gráfica en ggplot2 para anexar la fuente?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2, gráficas

Estoy haciendo una investigación y realizo gráficas en R, sin embargo, me gustaria que saliera una nota al pie de la gráfica para anexar la fuente, a continuación les muestro a que me refiero: me gustaría que apareciera como la nota que dice "Graphs by ¿Le gustaria consumir otra papa que no sea blanca?"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo ideal es usar el elemento `caption`, configurarlo mediante [`labs()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.1.0/topics/labs) y ajustarlo mejor con [`theme()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.1.0/topics/theme). Algo así:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=price)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y =..density..)) +
    scale_x_log10() +
    facet_wrap(. ~ cut) +
    labs(caption = "Graphs by ¿Le gustaria consumir otra papa que no sea blanca?") +
    theme(plot.caption=element_text(size=8, hjust=0.5, face="italic", color="black"))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, lo voy a aplicar y les comento el resultado